# Pointer & Range Pointer Problem with SfRadialGauge when using onCreateAxisRenderer for Custom Range in Flutter

Tags: flutter

In my App i have to make Speedo Meter to display users speed,

I created Design with Custom Ranges Successfully as (0 2 5 10 25 50 100 150 200 300 500 1000) as below.

[image]

As above image, Design has been done that i want.

But in this, problem is when i set value of Range Pointer and Needle Pointer to 60 its display needle pointer and range pointer is greater than 150. So please help me to how i can solve the problem.

And Second, how i can Display 1Gbps instead of 1000,

Below is My Source Code.

```
SfRadialGauge(axes: <RadialAxis>[
                                    RadialAxis(
                                      minimum: 0,
                                      maximum: 1000,
                                      showLastLabel: true,
                                      onCreateAxisRenderer: () {
                                        final CustomAxisRenderer renderer =
                                            CustomAxisRenderer();
                                        return renderer;
                                      },
                                      axisLabelStyle:
                                          GaugeTextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                      axisLineStyle: AxisLineStyle(
                                          thickness: 15.0,
                                          color: Colors.blueGrey[300]),
                                      minorTicksPerInterval: 1,
                                      minorTickStyle: MinorTickStyle(
                                          color: Colors.blueGrey[200], length: 7.0),
                                      majorTickStyle: MajorTickStyle(
                                          color: Colors.blueGrey[300],
                                          length: 10.0),
                                      pointers: <GaugePointer>[
                                        NeedlePointer(
                                            value: 60,
                                            // speed ?? 0.0,
                                            enableAnimation: true,
                                            needleStartWidth: 0,
                                            needleEndWidth: 5,
                                            needleColor: Colors.black,
                                            knobStyle: KnobStyle(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                borderColor: Colors.black,
                                                knobRadius: 0.06,
                                                borderWidth: 0.04),
                                            tailStyle: TailStyle(
                                                color: Colors.black,
                                                width: 5,
                                                length: 0.15)),
                                        RangePointer(
                                            value: 60,
                                            width: 15.0,
                                            enableAnimation: true,
                                            color:
                                                Color.fromARGB(255, 30, 64, 124)),
                                      ],
                                      annotations: <GaugeAnnotation>[
                                        GaugeAnnotation(
                                          widget: Text(
                                            curSpeed + " $unit",
                                            style:
                                                Themes.getTextStyleWhite(context),
                                          ),
                                          positionFactor: 1,
                                          angle: 90,
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    )
                                  ]),

class CustomAxisRenderer extends RadialAxisRenderer {
  CustomAxisRenderer() : super();

  /// Generated the 9 non-linear interval labels from 0 to 150
  /// instead of actual generated labels.
  @override
  List<CircularAxisLabel> generateVisibleLabels() {
    final List<CircularAxisLabel> _visibleLabels = <CircularAxisLabel>[];
    for (num i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      final double _value = _calculateLabelValue(i);
      final CircularAxisLabel label = CircularAxisLabel(
          this.axis.axisLabelStyle, _value.toInt().toString(), i, false);
      label.value = _value;
      _visibleLabels.add(label);
      _visibleLabels.map((e) => print("val:- ${e.value}"));
    }

    return _visibleLabels;
  }

  /// Returns the factor(0 to 1) from value to place the labels in an axis.
  @override
  double valueToFactor(double value) {
    // 2 5 10 25 50 100 150 200 300 500 1000
    if (value >= 0 && value <= 2) {
      return (value * 0.125) / 2;
    } else if (value > 2 && value <= 5) {
      return (((value - 2) * 0.125) / (5 - 2)) + (1 * 0.125);
    } else if (value > 5 && value <= 10) {
      return (((value - 5) * 0.125) / (10 - 5)) + (2 * 0.125);
    } else if (value > 10 && value <= 20) {
      return (((value - 10) * 0.125) / (20 - 10)) + (3 * 0.125);
    } else if (value > 25 && value <= 50) {
      return (((value - 25) * 0.125) / (50 - 30)) + (4 * 0.125);
    } else if (value > 50 && value <= 100) {
      return (((value - 50) * 0.125) / (100 - 50)) + (5 * 0.125);
    } else if (value > 100 && value <= 150) {
      return (((value - 100) * 0.125) / (150 - 100)) + (6 * 0.125);
    } else if (value > 150 && value <= 200) {
      return (((value - 150) * 0.125) / (200 - 150)) + (7 * 0.125);
    } else if (value > 200 && value <= 300) {
      return (((value - 200) * 0.125) / (300 - 200)) + (8 * 0.125);
    } else if (value > 300 && value <= 500) {
      return (((value - 300) * 0.125) / (500 - 300)) + (9 * 0.125);
    } else if (value > 500 && value <= 1000) {
      return (((value - 500) * 0.125) / (1000 - 500)) + (10 * 0.125);
    } else {
      return 1;
    }
  }

  /// To return the label value based on interval
  double _calculateLabelValue(num value) {
    if (value == 0) {
      return 0;
    } else if (value == 1) {
      return 2;
    } else if (value == 2) {
      return 5;
    } else if (value == 3) {
      return 10;
    } else if (value == 4) {
      return 25;
    } else if (value == 5) {
      return 50;
    } else if (value == 6) {
      return 100;
    } else if (value == 7) {
      return 150;
    } else if (value == 8) {
      return 200;
    } else if (value == 9) {
      return 300;
    } else if (value == 10) {
      return 500;
    } else {
      return 1000;
    }
  }
}
```

Please Help me, Thank You.